# How to change colour of histograms with facet_grid and the position of the text?

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

How can I change the colour for the two histograms plot made with facet_grid?
I would like to have the histogram of "Active" in green and "Failed" in red.

And also, how can I change the position of the text of the line in order to have it a bit more down?

Here is my code:

```
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = `Banks/turnover%Last avail. yr`)) +
  geom_histogram(
      bins = nclass.Sturges(`Banks/turnover%Last avail. yr`),colour = "black")+
  geom_vline(data = status_means, aes(xintercept = avg),  color="red", linetype="dashed")+
  geom_text(data = status_means , aes(x = avg, label = avg), y= Inf )+
  theme(legend.position="None")+
  facet_grid(~general_status)
```

[image]

Comment: For the text you can probably adjust the `vjust` parameter to 1 or higher to move it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a factor to the `fill` parameter. Here, I just use `active-failed` as I'm not sure how you have that distinguished in your data.

```
ggplot(df_all,
       aes(x = `Banks/turnover%Last avail. yr`, fill = as.factor(active-failed)))
```

Then, you can add a line to define the colors:

```
scale_fill_manual(values = c("green", "red"))
```

As @teunbrand said, you can just use `vjust` to move the text so that it is not cut off.

Remember to give a [good reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), it is helpful to provide some of your data via `dput(head(df))`.